# Inverse @OneToMany non updatable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Having the following entity:

```
@Entity
class Transaction implements Serializable {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  Long id

  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  Long trNumber

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  Set<Entry> entries = new HashSet()

  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  Date creationDate
}
```

I'd like entries to be impossible to update but @OneToMany doesn't allow the updatable = false attribute.

Here is the Entry entity:

```
@Entity
class Entry implements Serializable {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  Long id

  @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  Transaction transaction

}
```

I can use a JPA listener to throw an exception every time we try to update the Transaction but I'd like to set the updatable=false behavior at the entity level, as I do for the other attributes.

Comment: Does changing the CascadeType to something more restrictive (not ALL) work?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you can't achieve it using annotations in JPA 2.0. I've read in *"Pro JPA 2"* book from Apress that such read-only relationships are discussed for future versions of the specification.

I've had a similar problem which described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334216/manytooneupdatable-false-how-it-should-work). I've also asked the Expert Group for any comment [here](http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/users/archive/2011-12/message/0) (at the time of writing this post - no answer was given).

The cascading doesn't change a bit as you don't have to "merge" objects in order to change its state. You just can fetch the `Entry` which is moved to the managed state (it also makes its `Transaction` to be moved to the managed state), so each update must be reflected, at the end, in the database.

The `@JoinColumn(updatable=false)` seems to mean just that you cannot change the `Transaction` entity to something else - not that you cannot change its state.

You could detach the `Transaction` entity as soon as you fetch the `Entry`. In this case changes made to `Transaction` will be saved (it's managed) but to `Entry` won't (it's detached). You'd just need to remember to refresh the state of your `Entry` at the end, as your in-memory representation could be not equal to the database one.